# Sylius custom fields are not validated in form

Tags: forms, symfony, sylius

I am overriding the register page (overriding the Customer object) ; I have added "Type", which is a ChoiceType expanded (3 radio buttons), and I have added the defaultAddress fields (in which I have added 3 fields).
When I display the form, all these fields have a red star to show there are required, but when I submit the form, if I don't put anything in these fields, the form is submitted anyway and I have a database error because these fields are empty.

Here is my code :

CustomerRegistrationTypeExtension.php :

```
$builder->add('type', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => array('Particulier' => Customer::TYPE_PARTICULIER, 'Professionnel' => Customer::TYPE_PRO, 'Projet à but non lucratif' => Customer::TYPE_PROJET),
                'expanded' => true,
                'label' => 'Vous êtes',
                'choice_attr' => array('onclick' => 'alert(\"click\")')
        ])
        ->add('siren', TextType::class)
        ->add('denomination', TextType::class)
        ->add('defaultAddress', AddressType::class);
```

AddressTypeExtension.php

```
$builder->add('showOnMap', CheckboxType::class)
                ->add('geocodeLat', HiddenType::class)
                ->add('geocodeLng', HiddenType::class);
```

_address.html.twig :

```
{{ form_row(form.showOnMap, {'label' : 'address.showMap.label'}) }}
        {{ form_row(form.geocodeLat)}}
        {{ form_row(form.geocodeLng)}}
```

_form.html.twig

```
{{ form_row(form.type) }}
```

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Red asterisk near the field is just an UI feature. To require some fields, you must specify theirs validation configuration. Check out [Symfony validation documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html) to get required info, all of it should perfectly work in Sylius ;)

**One important thing** - remember to set *sylius* in `groups` parameter when defining constraints, it is a default validation group in Sylius.